# "flash":{} is added to my json output when json_encode is called inside the template of Slim PHP microframeork

Tags: php, json, mongodb, slim

Im trying to read some data from a Mongodb collection and return the result to my rest API. After query all docs from my Users collection, I send the resulting array to my template (Slim microframework here), and finally call json_encode() to send create the response. Here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//instancia o objeto Slim
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'templates.path' => 'templates'));

//List users
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017');
    $db = $mongo->mydatabase;
    $col = $db->users;
    $cursor = $col->find();
    $data = iterator_to_array($cursor, true);
    $app->render('default.php', $data, 200);
});

//run Slim
$app->run();

?>
```

The template dafault.php:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

If I call echo `json_encode($newa)` outside the template, everything works fine.

The output is:

```
{
flash: {}
54b71d4e097a4dcd4bf49684: {...}-
54bc5bd5cdce605e70325c4e: {...}-
}
```

Could anybody tell me where this "flash: {}" come from? and how can I make it go away?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flash` variable is added by Slim for [Flash Messaging](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Flash-Messaging-Overview) in your rendered output. You could disable the Flash middleware, but I expect you actually want to use a [Response object](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Response-Overview) instead of a rendered view:

```
<?php
    $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        $mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017');
        $db = $mongo->mydatabase;
        $col = $db->users;
        $cursor = $col->find();
        $data = iterator_to_array($cursor, true);
        $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')

        // print or echo output will be appended to Response
        echo json_encode($data);

        // Alternatively, explicitly set the Response body:
        // $app->response->setBody(json_encode($data));
    });
?>
```